# how customer_logged_in / out works?

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, xml, update-handle

I can't figure out how **`customer_logged_in`** and **`customer_logged_out`** work

```
<customer_logged_out>
...
</customer_logged_out>
```

where are they defined, how are they called?

---

EDIT

```
 <events>
    <controller_action_layout_load_before>
        <observers>
            <customer_is_logged_in_observer>
                <class>customer/observer</class>
                <method>beforeLoadLayout</method>
            </customer_is_logged_in_observer>
        </observers>
    </controller_action_layout_load_before>
```

I found out how this is triggered but i can't find the **controller_action_layout_load_before** event dispatcher

I have searched the project as a text but it doesn't show up in any file. Please shed some light on this.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hi @static how are you?,

The idea it's very simple. Using  You have the possibility to show/hide information for customer logged or not. That handles are executed in a observer, so for example in top menu to display log in or my account links are using that handle.

Let me know if you need more technical information. I glad to help you.

Best,
ALejandro.

Comment: thanks GrinGo, but yes i will need more technical info, if you can edit your post with the files and their location, and point to where and what is executed it would be nice.

Comment: it seems i am having trouble finding an event dispatcher for  controller_action_layout_load_before

Comment: @static I'm out from my laptop are you fine not or you can wait until tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

following events are used for customer login and customer logout

for customer login

`customer_login` event observer will be called. this function will be called the moment the customer logs in.you can see in the following `Mage_Customer_Model_Session` where the `customer_login` event has been called

```
public function setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer)
{
    $this->setCustomer($customer);
    $this->renewSession();
    Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_login', array('customer'=>$customer));
    return $this;
}
```

for customer logout

`customer_logout` event observer will be called. this function will be called the moment the customer logs out.you can see in the following `Mage_Customer_Model_Session` where the `customer_logout` event has been called

```
public function logout()
{
    if ($this->isLoggedIn()) {
        Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_logout', array('customer' => $this->getCustomer()) );
        $this->_logout();
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: I think the OP is referring to the layout handle, not the dispatched events

Comment: i dont think so that thr are layout handles present with customer_logged_out in magento

Comment: I can confirm that there are layout handles, check `customer.xml` file